# Problema com android studio usando flutter

Tags: android-studio, flutter

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Não consigo rodar meu projeto no emulador do android studio

Comment: Ali no primeiro combo box onde está escrito `<no devices>` não tem como selecionar o emulador? Aqui no meu também não fica habilitado esse 3 combobox, eu seleciono através do primeiro.

Answer (score -1):

Primeiramente e difícil identificar o problema mas roda flutter doctor "flutter doctor" ou "flutter doctor -v" no terminal
se tiver um erro ai vai mostrar
**Roda flutter doctor com as maquina virtual ligada **
Estou aqui para dar suporte

Comment: Carinha aqui é uma área para respostas, vamos tentar manter a organização do site? A sua "resposta" caberia melhor como uma comentário, caso ainda não possa comentar, aguarde que logo terá potuação suficiente!